# yum dependency failures - interpreting and resolving "Not found:", "Requires:", and "Removing:" messages when attempting a "yum update"

Tags: yum, rpm

I have a CentOS 7.9 server, successfully updated from CentOS 7.4 via the standard "yum update" command.

```
Install    18 Packages (+93 Dependent packages)
Upgrade  1219 Packages
```

(yum also replaced 16 packages)

The problem: yum is failing on a particular package, with messages that something cannot be found.

First, I ran `yum update --exclude=redhat-lsb-core`, to complete the bulk of the patching. I then ran `yum update`. These errors occurred:

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package redhat-lsb-core.x86_64 0:4.1-27.el7.centos.1 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-languages-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-cxx-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-printing-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-desktop-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
---> Package stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph.noarch 0:2015.1-1.atomic.el7 will be obsoleting
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: redhat-lsb-languages-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Removing: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Obsoleted By: stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph-2015.1-1.atomic.el7.noarch (AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_atomic_x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: redhat-lsb-cxx-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Removing: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Obsoleted By: stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph-2015.1-1.atomic.el7.noarch (AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_atomic_x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: redhat-lsb-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Removing: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Obsoleted By: stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph-2015.1-1.atomic.el7.noarch (AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_atomic_x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: redhat-lsb-desktop-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Removing: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Obsoleted By: stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph-2015.1-1.atomic.el7.noarch (AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_atomic_x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: redhat-lsb-printing-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Removing: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Obsoleted By: stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph-2015.1-1.atomic.el7.noarch (AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_atomic_x86_64)
               Not found
```

I interpret this as follows:

1. yum goes to update redhat-lsb-core, but determines that it has been
   obseleted (ie, superceded/replaced) by
   stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph
2. However, these packages depend on
   redhat-lsb-core: redhat-lsb-languages redhat-lsb-cxx redhat-lsb
   redhat-lsb-printing redhat-lsb-desktop ...
3. yum needs to install stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph,
   but cannot find it.

But point 3 doesn't seem right, that RPM can be found:

```
[root@parrot ~]# yum list stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph
Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, fastestmirror, langpacks, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager,
              : tracer_upload
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Available Packages
stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph.noarch                        2015.1-1.atomic.el7                         AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_atomic_x86_64
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
[root@parrot ~]#



[root@parrot ~]# yumdownloader stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_atomic_x86_64                                                                                      | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_cr_x86_64                                                                                          | 1.9 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_epel_7_x86_64                                                                                      | 2.3 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_extras_x86_64                                                                                      | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_os_x86_64                                                                                          | 2.3 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_sclo_x86_64_sclo                                                                                   | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_updates_x86_64                                                                                     | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph-2015.1-1.atomic.el7.noarch.rpm                                                             | 3.8 kB  00:00:00
[root@parrot ~]# ls -l stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph-2015.1-1.atomic.el7.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3940 May 27 03:36 stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph-2015.1-1.atomic.el7.noarch.rpm
[root@parrot ~]#
```

I tried `set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf`, but it had no effect.

I also tried directly installing the package that was doing the obsoleting, to no avail:

```
[root@parrot ~]# yum install stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph
Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, fastestmirror, langpacks, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager,
              : tracer_upload
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_atomic_x86_64                                                                                      | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_cr_x86_64                                                                                          | 1.9 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_epel_7_x86_64                                                                                      | 2.3 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_extras_x86_64                                                                                      | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_os_x86_64                                                                                          | 2.3 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_sclo_x86_64_sclo                                                                                   | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_updates_x86_64                                                                                     | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package redhat-lsb-core.x86_64 0:4.1-27.el7.centos.1 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-languages-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-cxx-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-printing-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-desktop-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
---> Package stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph.noarch 0:2015.1-1.atomic.el7 will be obsoleting
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: redhat-lsb-languages-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_os_x86_64)
           Requires: redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Removing: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_os_x86_64)
               redhat-lsb-core(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1
           Obsoleted By: stub-redhat-lsb-core-only-for-ceph-2015.1-1.atomic.el7.noarch (AcmeCorp_CentOS_7_x86_64_atomic_x86_64)
               Not found
```

Can anyone explain how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you clone this system? If so maybe a manual `rpm -e ...` can remove the problematic RPM without the `yum` dependency checks going sideways. But `rpm -e` on random modules might cause other things to go sideways...